# Use \subfloat in custom float/caption

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats

I am trying to use subfloats in a custom caption/float environment. But I get compilation errors.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,justification=centering,belowskip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev]{cleveref}

%%Charts
\DeclareCaptionType[fileext=loc,placement=b,within=chapter]{chart}[Chart][List of Charts] %list of charts is generated by \listofcharts
\crefname{chart}{chart}{charts}

\begin{document}

\begin{chart}[!h]
\centering%
\subfloat[Test 1]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Test1.pdf}\label{chrt:Tests:1}}%
\quad%
\subfloat[Test2]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Test2.pdf}\label{chrt:Tests:2}}%
\caption{Tests}%
\label{chrt:Tests}%
\end{chart}

\end{document}
```

If I change `\begin{chart}` to `\begin{table}` and `\end{chart}` to `\end{table}` this suddenly works...

Comment: RTFM, Section "2.1.2 The \newsubfloat Command"

Comment: Ok, I added \newsubfloat{chart} and now it sortof works. However cleveref doesn't seem to inherit the "chart" label from chart. Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: RTFM (cleveref), Section 7.1.2 "Customising Individual Cross-Reference Types" ;-)